# Using math mode input as "atoms" in chemmacros

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I am using the `ch` command in the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) package to typeset chemical formulas. Here are three examples as a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\ch{C-O-H}\\
\ch{i-j-k}\\
\ch{$i$-$j$-$k$}
\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

[image: bonds]

In the last example, I would like the i, j, and k to be in "italicized" form using math mode, which they are. But how can I get the bonds to have the correct length?

Comment: Out ot curiosity: Could you add some background information/context on how exactly someting like `i-j-k` would be used?

Answer (score 4):

First attempt succeeded!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{C-O-H}

\ch{i-j-k}

\ch{{$i$}-{$j$}-{$k$}}

\end{document}
```

[image]